# Create Parameterized Type of another class from existing ParameterizedType

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Consider this class structure.

```
class Class1<T> {
    Class2<T> field1;
}
```

If I have a `ParameterizedType` instance representing `Class1<String>` through reflection, how can I get/create a `ParameterizedType` instance representing `Class2<String>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In its current state the reflection API allows for (limited) inspection of generic type information. Since one could not leverage the newly constructed `ParameterizedType` there is little point in allowing its construction in the first place.

If you are building an API accepting `ParameterizedType`s and need users to construct their own, you might consider switching to guava's [`TypeToken`-Class](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

`ParameterizedType` is an interface. Simply write a class that implements it (or copy some existing implementation from the Internet) so that its methods return what you want.